# Dipole moment in aromatic compounds

Tags: dipole

Compare the dipole moment of the following:

- *o*-nitrophenol
- *o*-dichlorobenzene
- *o*-xylene

What I thought was:
*o*-dichlorobenzene should have the maximum, due to the acute angle and being more electronegative than the I- effect of $\ce{CH3}$ groups, and that *o*-nitrophenol would be the least since OH shows M+ and $\ce{NO2}$ is M- effect.

But the data from the internet says:
*o*-nitrophenol (3.01 D) > *o*-dichlorobenzene (2.67 D) > *o*-xylene (0.64 D)
How?

Comment: Think of it this way: o-xylene is a virtually undisturbed aromatic ring, o-dichlorobenzene is an aromatic ring with electrons slightly pulled towards chlorine, and o-nitrophenol is an aromatic ring with electrons pulled towards NO2 with great force, and also pushed to it from _another_ direction (should the direction be the same, maybe the effects would mostly negate each other, but this is not the case).

Comment: @IvanNeretin any reason why those effects dont cancel or atleast reduce the net moment?

Comment: Why, of course they do reduce it. In p-nitrophenol the dipole moment would be even greater. As to why they don't cancel out: why would they? Different directions, like I said.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Shouldn't the dipole moments in o-nitrophenol cancel out? I mean, -OH is strong donor, -NO2 is strong acceptor. Now if I try to draw vectors, they seem to slightly opposite to each other (not exactly! But at around 60 degrees from -OH dipole moment's head to -NO2 dipole moments tail.). A reasoning I found from an unreliable source suggest that, "o-nitrophenol has high dipole moment because of its ionic resonating structure". Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Like I said, of course they do _partially_ cancel out.